# Connecting to external API

Tags: web-services, api, static, proxy, ip

I am working on setting up a connection with an external service through their API.

The issue is that my calls to the API have to use an IP. I can't used a named domain to do this (this is outside of my control). I can only do this using a static IP, and my problem is that this particular service uses dynamic IPs.

I hope this situation makes sense.

My question is, is there some sort of alternative here that can help me proceed? Is there some sort of proxy or something that can help facilitate this? Essentially, in order for my project to connect to this API, I need to whitelist its IP, and I obviously can't do this if it's not a static IP.

Comment: If the IP is dynamic, how do you find out what it is?

Comment: Well, typically I would use the domain name, but in this case we are unable to reference a domain name and have to use an IP address. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

This service obviously doesn't want customers.

If you're learning the address manually, you have to update your settings manually.  If there is a programmatic way of getting the address (other than the typical DNS) then you need to implement code that fetches it and updates your settings.

Services can use a "[dynamic DNS service](https://www.google.com/webhp#q=dynamic%20dns%20service)" to allow easy access even when their IP address is not static, but this can be problematic and is considered un-professional.